# How to build a regular expression (C#) to identify a string of eight 1's & 0's

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to determine if a string contains a byte of binary digits, ex. 10010011.

I believe that [0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1] would work, but I'm sure theres a more efficient way of doing it, and being new to regular expressions, I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it needs to be exactly 8 (no more/less), use this:

```
@"(?<![01])([01]{8})(?![01])"
```

If you don't want to match something like "abc01010101xyz", use this:

```
@"\b[01]{8}\b"
```

If you want to match all 8-bit strings anywhere in the input, use this:

```
@"[01]{8}"
```

Be aware that if you feed the last pattern an input like `1111111100000000`, you're going to get a result set like:

```
11111111
11111110
11111100
11111000
...
00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification, even when I didn't know that I needed it yet!

Comment: I think you meant `(?<![01])[01]{8}(?![01])` for that first regex: "not preceded by `0` or `1`, and not followed by `0` or `1`".  Also, `[01]{8}` applied to `1111111100000000` yields exactly two hits: `11111111` and `00000000`.  It's *possible* to get overlapping matches like you showed, but it takes a lot of work.

Comment: @Alan Moore: Yeah, I like the lookaround version better. Edited. About the overlapping matches, I think it would depend on which regex options are in effect and which engine you're using.

Comment: In every regex flavor that I know of, non-overlapping matches is the rule.  Some flavors may make it a little *easier* to get overlapping results, but I don't know of any that work that way by default.

Answer (score 17):

That would be this one

```
[01]{8}
```

This `[0-1]` is not technically wrong, but "0-1" is hardly a range, so you can drop the dash.

Comment: WTF?! 10 up-votes for a two liner answer in less than 30 seconds. Something's seriously broken with SO's voting system.

Comment: @CanSpice Not necessary. But it's a clear trend that the thoughtful, longer answer do not nearly get as much attention as the mindless two-liners.

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, enjoy the rep (and the extra bronze badge!) :-)

Comment: @CanSpice: At least a more complete answer was accepted, that's fair enough.

Comment: @Tomalak: Maybe, but I gave yours +1 anyway. :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe `[01]{8}` should do it.

Answer (score 5):

```
[01]{8}
```

If you want to match exactly 8 zeros or ones (i.e. `101010101` won't match), then:

```
\b[01]{8}\b
```